# Change text colour of placeholder in select drop down - Material-ui

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I have a material-ui select component that presents a drop down of options to the user. The placeholder text shows as "select option" to tell the user to select the options they want. This is shown in light grey text, but because the text colour is so light it could be hard for colour blind people to read. Because of that I want to make the text colour darker but am not sure how. I don't want to make the placeholder one of the options within the dropdown if possible.

Code for the select component is:

```
<Select 
  options = {options}
  isMulti
  placeholder= "Select Options"
  value = {this.selectedOptions"
  onChange={this.changeH}
  className = SelectOptionsDropDown
/>
```

Styling within the .css file is:

```
.SelectOptionsDropDown {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
 }
```

This styling works fully

Comment: Please post the whole code

Comment: @ThanveerShah https://codesandbox.io/s/xp2jz5k3ow

Comment: The codesandbox you provided is not a working `Select` (e.g. no options are displayed when I click on it).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this approch?

```
<Select
fullWidth
size="small"
displayEmpty
inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'select' }}
value={age}
onChange={handleChange}/>
 <MenuItem value="" disabled>
    <em style={{color:"#9E9E9E"}}>Placeholder</em>
 </MenuItem>
 <MenuItem value={'A'}>Option A</MenuItem>
 <MenuItem value={'B'}>Option B</MenuItem>
 <MenuItem value={'C'}>Option C</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `::placeholder`, like below :

```css
.SelectOptionsDropDown::placeholder{
    color: red;
  }
```

Please note, it's not supported in IE, check [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder).

Comment: Hi, I added this in but it doesnt actually apply the changes, the styling I have at the moment applies fine though which is strange

Comment: The full code is too long to put somewhere but I can try replicating just this functionality into a codesandbox or something

Comment: I think, you have implemented Select of @material-ui in wrong way. Please check this demo for the same : https://codesandbox.io/s/6y86ywjmy3